# How to use channel properly for concurrent POST API call and log the data in File

Tags: go, goroutine, go-http

I am trying to design a HTTP client in Go that will be capable ofcConcurrent API calls to the web services and write some data in a textfile.

```golang
func getTotalCalls() int {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    ...
    return callInt
}
```

`getTotalColls` decide how many calls I want to make, input comes from terminal.

```golang
func writeToFile(s string, namePrefix string) {
    fileStore := fmt.Sprintf("./data/%s_calls.log", namePrefix)
    ...
    defer f.Close()
    if _, err := f.WriteString(s); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

The `writeToFile` will write data to file synchronously from a buffered channel.

```golang
func makeRequest(url string, ch chan<- string, id int) {
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"from": "Saru", "message": "Saru to Discovery. Over!"}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%d, %.2f, %d, %s, %s\n", id, secs, len(body), url, body)
}
```

This is the function which make the API call in a go Routine.

and Finally Here is the Main function, which send data from go routine to a bufferend channel and Later I range over the bufferend channel of string and write the data to file.

```golang
func main() {
    urlPrefix := os.Getenv("STARCOMM_GO")
    url := urlPrefix + "discovery"
    totalCalls := getTotalCalls()
    queue := make(chan string, totalCalls)

    for i := 1; i <= totalCalls; i++ {
        go makeRequest(url, queue, i)
    }

    for item := range queue {
        fmt.Println(item)
        writeToFile(item, fmt.Sprint(totalCalls))
    }
}
```

The problem is at the end of the call the buffered somehow block and the program wait forever end of all the call. Does someone have a better way to design such use case? My final goal is to check for different number of concurrent post request how much time it takes for each calls for bench marking the API endpoint for 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000 ... set of concurrent call.

Comment: Don't create a new http.Client for each request; [reuse one](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) (or at the very least its Transport). Closing and re-opening the file all the time is wasteful too.

Answer (score 3):

Something has to `close(queue)`. Otherwise `range queue` will block. If you want to `range queue`, you have to ensure that this channel is closed once the final client is done.

However... It's not even clear that you need to `range queue` though, since you know exactly how many results you'll get - it's `totalCalls`. You just need to loop this many times receiving from `queue`.

I believe your use case is similar to the [Worker Pools example on gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools), so you may want to check that one out. Here's the code from that example:

```
// In this example we'll look at how to implement
// a _worker pool_ using goroutines and channels.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Here's the worker, of which we'll run several
// concurrent instances. These workers will receive
// work on the `jobs` channel and send the corresponding
// results on `results`. We'll sleep a second per job to
// simulate an expensive task.
func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {

    // In order to use our pool of workers we need to send
    // them work and collect their results. We make 2
    // channels for this.
    const numJobs = 5
    jobs := make(chan int, numJobs)
    results := make(chan int, numJobs)

    // This starts up 3 workers, initially blocked
    // because there are no jobs yet.
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    // Here we send 5 `jobs` and then `close` that
    // channel to indicate that's all the work we have.
    for j := 1; j <= numJobs; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)

    // Finally we collect all the results of the work.
    // This also ensures that the worker goroutines have
    // finished. An alternative way to wait for multiple
    // goroutines is to use a [WaitGroup](waitgroups).
    for a := 1; a <= numJobs; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

Your "worker" makes HTTP requests, otherwise it's pretty much the same pattern. Note the `for` loop at the end which reads from the channel a known number of times.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to limit a number of simultaneous requests, you can use a semaphore implemented with a buffered channel.

```
func makeRequest(url string, id int) string {
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"from": "Saru", "message": "Saru to Discovery. Over!"}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d, %.2f, %d, %s, %s\n", id, secs, len(body), url, body)
}

func main() {
    urlPrefix := os.Getenv("STARCOMM_GO")
    url := urlPrefix + "discovery"
    totalCalls := getTotalCalls()
    concurrencyLimit := 50 // 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000.

    // Declare semaphore as a buffered channel with capacity limited by concurrency level.
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, concurrencyLimit)

    for i := 1; i <= totalCalls; i++ {
        // Take a slot in semaphore before proceeding.
        // Once all slots are taken this call will block until slot is freed.
        semaphore <- struct{}{}
        go func() {
            // Release slot on job finish.
            defer func() { <-semaphore }()
            item := makeRequest(url, i)
            fmt.Println(item)
            // Beware that writeToFile will be called concurrently and may need some synchronization.
            writeToFile(item, fmt.Sprint(totalCalls)) 
        }()
    }

    // Wait for jobs to finish by filling semaphore to full capacity.
    for i := 0; i < cap(semaphore); i++ {
        semaphore <- struct{}{}
    }
    close(semaphore)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to avoid any raise condition when writing into file. Other wise I have to add a new blocking and wait group to hold on when a go routine is writing in the file and other gorutines must wait. Which makes it more complex. But that code works fine. Thanks